# venv on AWS sagemaker notebook not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I just launched AWS Sagemaker studio and trying to create virtual environment to work with as below:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

venv works for my python scripts on Sagemaker. I am able to import the packages in my script as "import pandas as pd"

But When I tried opening a Jupyter notebook on Sagemaker and run `import pandas as pd` I am getting error as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

How do I use venv in my notebook? Thanks.

Comment: In my case, running the above three line to install from the requirements.txt it returns the following error:
Processing /tmp/build/80754af9/aiodns_1621353986406/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/aiodns_1621353986406/work'
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

SageMaker Studio notebooks run on apps that use docker images. Here is a workaround to use conda environments in SageMaker Studio notebooks (use EFS for persistence across app restarts)
https://github.com/durgasury/efs_backed_conda

I work at AWS and opinions are my own.